# Iterate over table to find a substring

Tags: sql, sqlite, substring, sql-like, exists

My table :

```
TABLE texts: 

(txt TEXT UNIQUE):
    blob
    abcdef
    WhAt7228
    _0jap
...
```

For `txt` I want to find substring in a given string (for example "megablob"). `if IS_SUBSTR(txt, "megablob"): return true` should return true because first element "blob" is a substring of "megablob".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` which returns `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.

For case-sensitive search use `INSTR()` function:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE INSTR('megablob', txt));
```

For case-insensitive search use `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 'megablob' LIKE '%' || txt || '%');
```

Comment: In both cases, it would stop on the first occasion?

Comment: @baronsec EXISTS returns as soon as it finds the 1st row that satisfies the condition.

Comment: You might try
SELECT txt from texts WHERE 0 < CHARINDEX('megablob',txt)

Comment: @Jan CHARINDEX() is not supported by SQLite. Even if it was supported the query would not return false if there is no row in the table containing 'blob'.